# Better pattern for antMatchers in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, security, url

I've implemented a ResourceServerConfig class extending ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter , following the Spring Security working method,
and i'm asking myself if there is a better way to do it.

Let me show my code:

```
private static final String version = "/v1";

         http
            .authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers("/v1/configtag*","/v1/configtag/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/v1/extensions*","/v1/extensions/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/v1/logging*","/v1/logging/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/v1/searchpath*","/v1/searchpath/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/v1/groups*","/v1/groups/*").hasRole("ADMIN")

            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();

             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
             .csrf().disable();
```

The problem is that i was expecting to block USER in accessing that specified paths , but ( maybe caused from the anyRequest().authenticated) actually USER can access that paths!!!

How can i solve? Note that if we cut off anyRequest().authenticated , i'll have to specify a matcher for every path ( i think )

Ps: there is a unique String to do this
`.antMatchers("/v1/configtag*","/v1/configtag/*")` ?

Thanks in advance and have a great day

Comment: what is the error you are getting when .antMatchers("/v1/**").hasRole..

Comment: @dimitrisli in the beginning, i've started configuring with that 2 rows.
I've tried changing the order , but v1/**  would never overcome  the other matcher. I was expecting that first triggers before the other, but i've met some issue

Comment: not sure I understand. Can you add this information in the description along with the error because this seems to be the right path and need more info for people to be able to help troubleshoot

Comment: updating totally